# react component implementing a custom sliding notification

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am writing a `SimpleNotification` component that will slide into view when `show()` is called and slide out when `dismiss()` is called.

Currently, I have two problems.

[image]

First I want the message and the cross button on the same line, even when the message overflows. And the cross button should always be on the right of the message. And the cross button should be round and have its content centered.

The second problem is I don't know how to add sliding animation (is this transition animation?) when `show()` or `dismiss()` is called. So now I temporarily use a bool `visible` to control its visibility instead of letting it slide in and out.

How can I achieve what I want? Thanks in advance!

I am new to front end and below in my current attempt.

```
class SimpleNotification extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            visible: false
        }
        this.style = {
            card: {
                width: "fit-content",
                minWidth: "300px",
                padding: "10px",
                boxShadow: "0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)",
                float: "right",
            },
            cross: {
                display: "inline",
                margin: "10px",
                backgroundColor: "#D3D3D3",
                borderRadius: "50%",
                width: "22px",
                height: "22px",
                textAlign: "center"
            },
            message: {
                display: "inline",
                margin: "10px",
                width: "80%",
                wordWrap: "break-word",
            },
            transition: {
                transition: "all 0.5s linear"
            },
        }
        // Replace existing notification
        this.call_stack = []
    }

    show(message = "", duration = 2000){
        // transition: width 2s, height 4s;
        this.call_stack.push({message: message, duration: duration})
        let count = this.call_stack.length
        this.setState({visible: true, message})
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (this.call_stack.length == count)
                this.dismiss()
            this.call_stack.splice(count - 1, 1)
        }, 10000000)
    }

    dismiss(){
        this.setState({visible: false})
    }

    render() {
      const {visible, message} = this.state
      return visible ? <div id={this.props.id} style={this.style.card}>
          <p style={this.style.message}>{message}</p>
          <p style={this.style.cross} onClick={this.dismiss.bind(this)}>×</p>
      </div> : null
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First issue can be solved by placing x in different div

```
<div className="row">
  <div className="col-11">
     Text here
  </div>
  <div className="col-1">
    X
  </div>
</div>
```

Second problem can be solved using conditionally applying class.

```
    .hiden{
transform: translateX(-300px) // width of you notification container
transition: all 0.5s;
}

.open{
transform: translateX(0);
}
```

apply above css conditionally like

```
<div className={`hiden ${state.open? 'open': ''}`}>
```

Comment: How do you make the X appear on the rightmost of the notification?

Comment: And I am using React, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to apply css.

Comment: And the X is not round, as displayed in the picture above.

Comment: apply css make background of x ground. checkout to make background round in stackoverflow or google

Answer (score -1):

To make the message and close icon stay on the same row, you can use flexbox.

```css
.message-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.cross {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
}

.message {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

I've wrapped the message and cross in a container, which gives them the correct layout.

The card is defaulted to closed, then a card__open class dynamically applied when there are any messages

```css
.card {
  width: fit-content;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  transition: top 0.5s;
}

.card__open {
  top: 20px;
}
```

The [Classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames#readme) library is great for dynamically definining which classes should be applied

```
const classes = classNames({
    card: true,
    card__open: messages.length
  });


return (
    <div className={classes}>
    ...
```

I've created a small example of how you could apply animations.

[CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/nervous-bash-7p0xg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)